# Failed to declare data and help to save file to desktop

Tags: c#

I have this code that prints the values of a database in sql, the program captured the data in an excel sheet but for licensing reasons I had to make it save it to a csv file

The values that are seen there are those that are being used, I am not very expert in the language but I understand it enough. The only thing that the code does is print in a csv file the first line, but I want it to add all the values of the database that are going to be getting

```
private void SaveCSV()
    {
        string dataDay = DateTime.Today.ToString().Replace("/", "");
        dataDay = dataDay.Replace(":", "");
        dataDay = dataDay.Replace(" ", "");

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        string filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "Registro_" + dataDay + ".csv";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = filter;
        const string header = "Fecha,Serial,Estacion,Nombre,Estatus,Distancia,Fuerza,Vacio,Presion,Tiempo ciclo,Total Ensamblados,Ensamblado a";
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int FilasCount = dataGridViewResults.RowCount;
            filter = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            writer = new StreamWriter(filter);
            for (int i = 0; i < FilasCount; i++)
            {
                string fecha = dataGridViewResults["fecha,", i].Value.ToString();
                string serial = dataGridViewResults["serial,", i].Value.ToString();
                string estacion = dataGridViewResults["estacion,", i].Value.ToString();
                string nombre = dataGridViewResults["nombre,", i].Value.ToString();
                string estatus = dataGridViewResults["estatus,", i].Value.ToString();
                string distancia = dataGridViewResults["distancia,", i].Value.ToString();
                string fuerza = dataGridViewResults["fuerza,", i].Value.ToString();
                string vacio = dataGridViewResults["vacio,", i].Value.ToString();
                string presion = dataGridViewResults["presion,", i].Value.ToString();
                string tiempociclo = dataGridViewResults["tiempociclo,", i].Value.ToString();
                string total_enamblados = dataGridViewResults["total_ensamblados,", i].Value.ToString();
                string ensamblado_a = dataGridViewResults["ensamblado_a", i].Value.ToString();
            }
            writer.WriteLine(header);
            writer.WriteLine(saveFileDialog); 
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText();
            writer.Close();


        }

    }
```

Comment: You’re not writing anything in the loop and I’m not sure this code even compiles...

Comment: writer.WriteLine(header);       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName,saveFileDialog.Filter);
 writer.Close();
Sorry this is the ultimate part of code